# Daylight Saving and postdated times

Tags: user-interface, dst

We recently changed our application in an attempt to support displaying times in the timezone that the time was recorded in. We have run into a problem with getting times correct on Daylight Saving changes.

We implemented it by storing the offset separately but the UTC time for each time. Then when displaying the time, we add the static offset to the UTC time to show the time the user entered.

The issue we are running into is entering times that occurred before the time change. We are converting the entered time to UTC, but the conversion back is typically an hour off.

Obviously the problem is we are storing the offset of the "current" local time and not the offset of the time that the user entered time represents. But most of our users do not follow thru with the time change during the course of the event. So if they are documenting times at 1:55 and they need to document a time 10 minutes later they would put 2:05 instead of 3:05.

This would seem to preclude the use of using IsDaylightSavingTime and altering the display time with using the "appropriate" offset.

So I am kinda stuck on what to do to display the time that the user entered despite what the offset "should be".